# post items from to amazon.com using API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, amazon-mws

What API I should use to post items from asp.net (C#) web application to amazon.com ? 
please guide me to proper documentation and steps.

What I am looking for is how to add new item into certain category and pass the item title/description/pictures/price etc... -- plz advice

Thanks

Comment: I dont think these answers is what I am looking for - how I can pass Item title/description/picture/price etc... plz advice

Answer (score 1):

You're question is a bit vague, but this was the most useful link I found when researching into how to interface with Amazon using C# -

http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/

Answer (score 1):

You need the Marketplace Web Services API.  Found at http://developer.amazonservices.com.

You then need the flat file feed specifications to send the flat file in the correct format to the MWS.  That can be found after you're logged into your seller central account:

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=ag_13461_cont_help?ie=UTF8&itemID=13461&language=en_US

From there, you can simply send to the MWS the data you need.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
SubmitFeedRequest req = new SubmitFeedRequest();

        req.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(feedContent);
        feedContent.Position = 0;
        req.FeedContent = feedContent;
        req.FeedType = "_POST_FLAT_FILE_INVLOADER_DATA_";
        req.PurgeAndReplace = false;
        req.Marketplace = MarketPlaceId;
        req.Merchant = MerchantId;

        return Service.SubmitFeed(req);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that by 'posting' you mean posting new items into the amazon marketplace, you can use 
this api https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Also google works wonders for searching

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like you need the Amazon Market Place Feeds API.

https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=feeds&group=bde&version=latest

You can use SubmitFeed to send product and inventory information to Amazon